# Stub generation failes with obsolete attribute, Pex v0.94.51023.0

Tags: pex, moles

I have an interface with a method marked with the obsolete attribute. The attributes *error* parameter is set to *true* to throw an exception when used. The problem is this causes the stub to not generate for the whole class. When I alter the value to *false* the stub generates as expected.

I’m looking for a way to generate the stub while retaining the *error* parameter as *true*.

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Start();

    [Obsolete("this is obsolete Stop, stop using it", true)]
    void Stop();
}
```

I’ve tried different permutations of.

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
  <Assembly Name="My.Car.Services"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <TypeFilter TypeName="ICar" SkipObsolete="true" />
  </StubGeneration>
</Moles>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. When a method is marked at Obsolete(..., true), C# will not allow to instantiate an class implementing that interface.