# Microsoft Moles does not generate Stub or Mole for types with obsolete members

Tags: moles, pex

We were successfully generating stubs and moles for third party vendor assemblies for our unit tests. With their recent updates a lot of types are being ignored as certain methods have been declared obsolete(...,true). Is there a work around at all. We want to avoid starting from scratch using a new mocking tool..

Answer (score 2):

See: [Stub generation failes with obsolete attribute, Pex v0.94.51023.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839004/stub-generation-failes-with-obsolete-attribute-pex-v0-94-51023-0)
"This is by design. When a method is marked at Obsolete(..., true), C# will not allow [you] to instantiate [a] class implementing that interface."

Comment: I was hoping that while generating a stub/mole for a Type, Moles framework would be able to ignore the specific members that have been marked with obsolete attribute..The compiler would not complain then.. am I missing something?

Comment: C# does let you instantiate classes that implement interfaces with obsolete members...